# adding target attribute to <a> that have hrefs other than "#!"

Tags: jquery, html

I have loads of html `a` tags like this in my HTML:

```
<a href="#!></a>
<a href="something.html">
```

And I want every `a` `href` that is not `#!` to add attribute target="_blank".

I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($('a').attr('href').length > 3){
      $(this).attr("target","_blank");
  }
});
```

But this doesn't work any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').each(function(index){
      if($(this).attr('href') != '#!')
           $(this).attr("target","_blank");
   });
});
```

Comment: Ah, shoot, you beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed the quotes...

```
<a href="#!"></a>
```

And

```
if($(this).attr('href') != '#!')
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your markup is invalid... `<a href="#!"></a>` should be how it's written... in your example, you're missing the closing double-quotes for the href attribute...

For another thing, you're checking $('a') which is going to return an array of anchor tags. Arrays do not have an `href` attribute, so it's going to die, right there.

I think what you're looking for is something like

```
$("a").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("href").length > 3) {
        $(this).attr("target","_blank");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using jQuery.not function.
http://jsfiddle.net/wPa8S/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").not("[href='#!']").prop("target", "_blank");
});
```